# Need help on configuring BIND, BIND-CHROOT on Centos 6

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, centos, domain, bind

New to linux and just wonna test out hosting my own domain and respective zone file.
Have already delegated nameservers/IP for that domain and created the DNS records.

Installed BIND with Chroot and other stuff.

```
yum install bind bind-chroot bind-libs bind-utils
```

So now I have my zone file all setup it seems, just not sure where they want me to stick it
and where is the main configuration file for Bind which states which conf files and or
folders hold the zone records etc.

If someone could give me the ABC's on configuring BIND to listen for all IP's,
setting correct permissions if required and where to place my DNS records/Zone file and which if any changes need to be made to the main BIND configuration file wherever it is would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can many howtos such as: http://www.howtoforge.com/bind-installation-on-centos and http://www.centos.org/docs/2/rhl-rg-en-7.2/s1-bind-configuration.html